# getting error while using pdftk tool

Tags: perl

for performing the pdf modifications install the cpan module PDF::Tk [Perl integration for the pdf toolkit (pdftk)], but while using the functionality of pdftk getting the below set of error, Can anyone please help me in resolving this.

code samples used:
script name: test.pl --  used to reverse the pdf contain
1)use PDF::Tk;

```
pdftk inputPDF.pdf cat end-1 output outPDF.pdf  
==> Can't locate IO/All.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5 /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/PDF/Tk.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/PDF/Tk.pm line 2.
Compilation failed in require at testPDF.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at testPDF.pl line 1.
```

2) use PDFTk;

```
pdftk inputPDF.pdf cat end-1 output outPDF.pdf
==>Can't locate PDFTk.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5 /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at testPDF.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at testPDF.pl line 1.
```

Comment: Double check that the IO::All module is actually installed or installed in the defined path with the correct premissions. I realize module installers SHOULD install all required module dependencies, but I have seen in a few rare cases where that did not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your second example. You're talking about [PDF::Tk](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Tk), so I don't know why you're trying to use a module called PDFTk. I think we can safely ignore that.

Your first example looks like it's getting further. It has found PDF::Tk and is trying to load it. But something is loading [IO::All](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) which is apparently missing from your system.

So the solution is to install IO::All. But it makes me wonder how you installed PDF::Tk. Any sane module installation method will also pull in any required modules (and IO::All is [clearly listed as a required module](https://metacpan.org/source/MRAMBERG/PDF-Tk-0.02/META.yml) for PDF::Tk).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Rick and Dave. after installing the PDF::Tk module when i check the list of modules installed in linux environment using command "instmodsh" used to display list of installed modules in a system. for PDF::Tk, it was showing me as "PDFTk". so in my second example i was tiring with alternatives.

Comment: In one of my application have a requirement to encrypt pdf file while saving and decrypt while downloading pdf file by owner.Could you please let me know the ways to implement this functionality.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should put it in a new post.

Comment: I installed all the dependence module for PDF::Tk and tried to run the script getting error as "Can't locate object method "pdftk" via package "inputPDF" (perhaps you forgot to load "inputPDF"?) at testPDF.pl line 2."